# UITableViewCell in iOS 7/8 has gap on left

Tags: ios, uitableview, insets

Ever since I upgraded to iOS 7, the image on the UITableViewCell has a gap on left. It seems to be the same for iOS 8 beta.

After reading many answers here, I have tried:

- set Custom Separate Insets in IB to 0
- set tableView.SeparatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.Zero;

Only custom table cell seems to work... but my code breaks in iOS 8 (now everything mess up and image overlapped with text).

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:IS_IPAD ? CGRectMake(0, 0, 137, 103) : CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 74)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"song%d.png", row + 1]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Wonder anybody has a solution on this?

Comment: This now works fine in iOS 8 final.